# Extract a table from ajax response

Tags: jquery

I take a whole html code for page for extracting a table. Here is my code.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hello");
        $.ajax(
        {
        url: '/Member/DownloadUrlData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {

        },
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data);
            var theHtml = $(data).filter('#container>table:first').html();
            $("#rData").append(theHtml);

       },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    },
        complete: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
       }
   });
    });
```

but i cant extract the table.the problem shown in error log is  jquery cannt access "" in the data. how can i remove this.

Comment: `jQuery` will automatically remove any unnecessary tags like `html`, `head` and `body`

Comment: What's exactly the problem? What you get? What would you like to get? Where? When? How? Why?

Comment: Please show us what you get in `data`

Comment: whats the issue y you want to remove..?:O:O

Comment: i want to extract the div "container" from "data". data contain all the html of a particular page. And i also want to add this table to another div rData. But in the console i got an error msg,Syntax error, unrecoganized !Doctype html

Comment: data page contain the all html for the url http://rid3201.org/site/club_members2.php?id=MTk3Ng==

Comment: you can use ```load()``` with fragment hash to extract html element from ajax content: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Yukulélé :not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

`var theHtml = $(data).filter('#container>table:first').html();`

`$(data)` will expose all the children of the immediate children of the `body` element, but `#container>table:first` can't be a child of the `body` element, since `table` is explicitly a child of `#container`.

Maybe you meant this?

`var theHtml = $(data).filter('#container').children('table:first').html();`

**EDIT:** In response to the theory that the `data` returned is malformed HTML:

If jQuery returns a syntax error when it tries to parse `$(data)`, that means the HTML is malformed. The problem is that jQuery can accept all sorts of arguments: `$()` will function differently depending on whether it is given:

- A selector
- XML or HTML
- A function

If the XML or HTML string is malformed, it will try to interpret it as a selector — which causes the error. To force it to parse as HTML, use the following expression:

`$.parseHTML(data)`

instead of

`$(data)`

But ideally you wouldn't have to do this: the root of the problem is with the HTML returned by your AJAX request, which may cause hiccups elsewhere. I would recommend passing that response through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to see if you can correct the problem with the markup.

Comment: What does `$(data)` return? What does `$(data).filter('#container')` return? Help us help you!

Comment: data return the whole html and $(data).filter('#container') return Syntax error, unrecoganized !Doctype html

Comment: Aha! In that case, it means the HTML returned in `data` is malformed, and jQuery can't parse it. I've added to the answer above.

Comment: problem shown in error log is '#container>table:first' is not a function

Comment: That's very odd. Is it still giving you this problem after attempting my fix?